# How to pass object with named path in rails 3.1.0?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

There are rfqs and quotes controllers in our rails 3.1.0 app. Rfq has many quotes and quote belongs_to a rfq. We want to list all quotes in index and we can not use the nested resources(resources :rfqs do ...). Now we are facing a challenge to pass the rfq id into the new_quote_path. What's the right way to accomplish this? Thanks so much.

Comment: Could you give some examples of the routing structure you are after ?  Why can you not use nested resources ? Seems like the solution you are after

Comment: If using nested resources, like resources :rfq do resources :quotes end, then index can not list all quotes but the quotes only for a specific rfq.

Answer (score 2):

you could add a path in routes.rb to the controller you want like so

```
match "/rfqs/:id/quotes/:qoute_id" => 'rfq#show'
```

then link to it from your views like:

```
href="/rfqs/<%=rfq.id%>/quotes/<%=qoute.id%>"
```

and handle it in your controller

```
if params[:id] && params[:qoute_id]
  @rfq = RFQ.find(params[:id])
  @quote = Quote.find(params[:qoute_id])
end
```

I'll admin this is not the most elegant solution but it works just fine.

Comment: +1. Some people seem to think they always have to use whatever is built-in to the framework, but if it doesn't work quite the way you want, there's nothing wrong with "rolling your own", or just doing something really simple and "dumb".

Comment: Is it possible to pass a rfq id into quote controller as this: new_quote_path(:rfqid => @rfq.id) and retrieve the rfqid in quote controller with params[:rfqid]? thanks.